# how to view all tables in postgresql database from outside network?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have hosted the PostgreSQL database in one of the local network.
with the help of the fourm and other blogs. I could able to manage the connect the database from other computers. I modified the PostgreSQL configuration file to allow all IP to access the database.

I could connect to the DB. But I could not view any of the tables in that. I am using pgAdmin tool to connect. Pgadmin tool is getting connected, I see all activities, but I could view any of the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:- by following method.

i found that there was two postgresql installed in the system 10 & 12.
The db which i connected to 12.
But the openproject tables to 10.
So i uninstalled the postgresql 12.
I configured the postgresql to allow all ip in the configuration file.
after restart the postgresql. i could able to view all the tables.
thank you so much for everyone help

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, do you you have any specific schema that you have created the tables in for a particular database?

Also, when you say you are connected to the database I have a feeling that you are connected to the default db "Postgres" and not your user db.

To switch the database in pgamdin click on databases on the left side and then double click or connect to the user database (your db) and you should be able to see the tables inside it.

Try it out and in case it doesn't work you can always use terminal to connect to your database using the below command:

```
psql -h hostname -d databasename -U username
```

This prompts for the password, enter the pass and user the below commands to list out the db's

`\l` >>> lists the dbs out.

in case you are connected to postgres and you want to switch user:

```
\c databasename
```

once connected to the db which has your tables, list them out using this:

```
\dt
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: which one did you try? pgadmin or terminal? are you able to view the tables locally from the server ?

Comment: I tried in pgadmin. i am using ubuntu as my computer.

Comment: can you share the screen shot what's visible to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the details below.

```
root@OpenProject:/home/XXXXXXXX# psql -h 192.168.1.146 -d openproject -U vivek 
Password for user vivek:  
psql (12.1 (Ubuntu 12.1-1.pgdg18.04+1)) 
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

openproject=> \l openproject=> \c SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3,
cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off) You are
now connected to database "openproject" as user "craftsilicon".
openproject=> \dt Did not find any relations. openproject=> \l
                                List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |     Access privileges     
-------------+----------+----------+---------+-------+---------------------------  
 openproject | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =Tc/postgres    +
             |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres    +
             |          |          |         |       | craftsilicon=CTc/postgres  
 postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN |   
 template0   | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =c/postgres              +
             |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres  
 template1   | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =c/postgres              +
             |          |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres 
(4 rows)

openproject=> \c SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher:
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off) You are now
connected to database "openproject" as user "craftsilicon".
openproject=> \dt Did not find any relations.
```

I dont know, where the tables are stored for the openproject and i
want to access the tables.

Comment: root@OpenProject:/home/craftsilicon# psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.1 (Ubuntu 12.1-1.pgdg18.04+1)
root@OpenProject:/home/craftsilicon# locate bin/postgres
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres
/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres

i dont know which database is openproject is connected and working. how to find and create new username and password to connect to DB.